# Virtualbox issue: how to use static ip in linux guest with windows host using dynamic ip?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, debian, linux-mint, static-ip

I'm using windows 7 as host OS, then I installed linux mint debian as guest OS.

My Windows 7 is using dynamic ip. Here is the setting:

```
ip: 192.168.1.101
mask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Currently network adapter in virtualbox is using NAT.

If I want to use static ip in linux guest OS, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want network connection (so access to your LAN) select Bridged Adapter in the VirtualBox settings > Network. On linux you can set the ip in /etc/network/interfaces. When done, reboot the interface with ifdown *interface* & ifup *interface* (or service networking restart).

```
iface *interface* inet static
address *ipaddress*
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway *gateway*
```

Comment: I think I found the GUI tool for to do this :) (Menu -> Administration -> Network), pardon for my laziness, once a windows user. I had put the static ip address and subnet mask, but I don't know what value to put for the gateway address. Do you know?

Comment: Gateway address is your router IP.

Comment: so it's same as the windows host OS has? 192.168.1.1 ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: alright, it seems working fine, let's see for two days. Btw, are you sure your code above is applicable for debian? I just checked /etc/network/interfaces, the contents is different. There is no "=" sign at all.

Comment: Oh my bad. Posted for CentOS :)  Changed it now.

Comment: @jeroen After searching for 2 days and trying a zillion options - I ended up on this (quite old) thread for the second time and decided to try it and lo and behold! In my interfaces file I also have the lines: network and broadcast: iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.8.250
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.8.0
broadcast 192.168.8.255
gateway 192.168.8.1
I dont know if that did the trick but I'm a happy camper